# I want to remove the GADBannerView after InAppPurchase

Tags: ios6, view, xcode4.2, adbannerview, superview

In my app i used the InApp purchase after that i want to remove the adds from the GADBannerView but still adds displayed.

**Any Ideas**

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your product id is "com.yourcompany.ReduceAdds" set the boolean to Yes, see below.

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"com.yourcompany.ReduceAdds"];

In viewDidLoad

if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"com.yourcompany.ReduceAdds"]){
        [bannerView_ loadRequest:[self request]];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"no ads. user bought inapp item");
    }